# What is 見ちゃおれん here?

Tags: meaning

In the follow manga panel:

[image]

I'm not sure about 「見ちゃおれん」. Is this 見ては居れない = 見てちゃだめだ　"(You) should watch"?  My other guess is おれ＝俺.

Context: The man is scolding the girl (he hired to be the stall mascot) for not doing her job properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

見ちゃおれん is indeed a fairly casual way of saying 見てはおれない (= 見てはいられない). However, 見てちゃだめ is more like 'you *shouldn't keep* watching' (not an uncomplicated 'you shouldn't watch' like 見ちゃだめ),  and 見てはいられない is more 'I can't bear to watch' than 'shouldn't watch' anyway.

Comment: `見てちゃだめ is 'you shouldn't watch'` <- "You shouldn't watch" is 見ちゃだめ, rather than 見**て**ちゃだめ, right?

Comment: @Chocolate 見てちゃだめ is what OP wrote up there, and I just wrote it the way they did. Do native speakers ever say 見てちゃだめ, or was it just a mistake by OP?

Comment: I think it was a mistake. ては→ちゃ, so みてはだめ→みちゃだめ. みてちゃだめ is a shortened form of みていちゃだめ = みていてはだめ, which is more like "you shouldn't keep/be watching". I think we say things like テレビばっかり見てちゃだめよ！ 勉強しなさい！