# Constructing て-form of ～ちゃくれない

Tags: て-form, construction

In this sentence:

> 夜は貫いちゃくれないよ

I'm having trouble constructing the phrase 貫いちゃくれない.

From what I understand, it should be parsed like this:

貫く + て-form + しまう(ちゃう) + て-form + くれる + ない

But this makes 貫いちゃってくれない, and I don't know how it is possible to reduce it, since words like やっちゃって retains ゃっ.

Is there an explanation of how the って further collapses, or is there an alternate way to parse the phrase?

**Edit:**

I think related links in the comments probably applies here, where ちゃ is reduced from ては, so marking this as duplicate is probably fair.

For context, the previous line was this:

> 願ってたって終んないよ。
>
> 夜は貫いちゃくれないよ

It's something along the lines of "it won't come true even if I wished for it for the whole night", I believe.

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57943/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78257/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/84647/9831

Comment: @Chocolate I assumed ちゃ was simply ては but I still have no idea what the sentence says. Is it clear without the context?

Comment: @user3856370 Right, the sentence can be rephrased 夜は貫いてはくれないよ, but I have no idea what it means, either.